# How do I host a Jekyll blog on a github subdirectory?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I would like to create a blog using Jekyll on a subdirectory of my main repo on Github. At the moment I have a landing page/portfolio at [www.jonbstrong.com](http://www.jonbstrong.com) and would like to create the jekyll blog in `www.jonbstrong.com/blog`

The instructions on the [Jekyll quickstart guide](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html) only refer to when you want to install the blog in your main repo.

Comment: I don't see an actual question being asked here. Can you elaborate on what you're asking, and what you've tried that isn't working?

Comment: I'm asking: how do I install a jekyll blog on a github subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a `blog` repository and send your Jekyll files in it (gh-pages branch). You will then be able to reach www.jonbstrong.com/blog.

Edit:
User/organization repository are published in `master` branch. Any other repository like username.github.io/repositoryName are published in `gh-pages` branch.

```
git checkout -b gh-pages
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit in gh-pages branch"
git push origin gh-pages
```

Done.

Comment: I've created a blog repository and created a jekyll blog there, however I wasn't sure how to us pages rather than master and I'm unable to reach it using the www.jonbstrong.com/blog address. Here is the full list of commands I used:


jekyll new myblog  |  cd myblog  |   jekyll serve  |    git init  |  git add -A  |  git commit -m "first commit"  |  git remote add origin  |  https://github.com/jonbstrong/blog.git  |  git push -u origin master`

Comment: thanks so much for your help! However I'm now seeing some rather odd layout on http://jonbstrong.com/blog/ it seems that the jekyll installation is missing styles or something has gone wrong..

Comment: in your  `_config.yml`, you have to set `baseurl: "/blog"`